# Download outlook email attachment to local drive using r

Tags: outlook, download, attachment

I am using a script from [here](https://fewmorewords.com/from-email-attachments-to-a-single-table/).

However, when I execute it, I keep getting the following error:

```
<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo 
CheckErrorInfo -2147352567 
Error: Exception occurred
```

To make sure the script is checking my attachment correctly, I printed the attachment `name` and `save path`. `Print` shows the correct `name` and `path`, but it does not save any attachment.

Can you help me whit this? :)

Comment: Which line of code exactly fires an exception at runtime? Did you try to run the code under the debugger?

Comment: Error was coming at code line to save attachment. I found the issue.Windows uses "backward slash" instead of "forward slash" in R. So when you give the file path where you want to save the attachment, you need to change "forward slash" to "double backward slash".

Example using gsub:

attachment_file<-paste0(gsub("/","**\\\\\\\\**",getwd()), "\\\\", attachmentname)

Comment: I found someone posted similar issue. I posted solution that worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55486537/save-attachments-extracted-from-e-mail-by-iterating/63064091#63064091